# How to update git working copy to a specific commit while staying on the same branch?

Tags: git

Say I have my working copy on a clean `master` branch. What I want is to bring the whole code to the state it was at a certain commit but without actually switching to that commit / detaching HEAD.

I can achieve that using these steps:

1. Create a copy of the whole working copy directory;
2. Checkout the new copy to the commit that I want my code to be in the state of;
3. Get rid of the `.git` directory and bring the one from the original working copy (that is still at clean `master`):

Here is an example illustrating what I want in the end:

```
mkdir code
cd code/
git init .
echo 'content 1' > file.txt
git add --all && git commit -m 'version 1' && git tag v1
echo 'content 2' > file.txt
git add --all && git commit -m 'version 2' && git tag v2
cd ..
cp -pr code code1
cd code1/
git checkout v1
rm -rf .git
mv ../code/.git ./

git diff
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 4d4bc1c..a0054e4 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-content 2
+content 1

git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   file.txt
```

The question is: how to achieve that using git commands only and not juggling the `.git` folders? Something like `git bring-to-the-state-of hash/branch/tag`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer appears to give you exacly what you want with `--patch`.  But to answer the title of your question, you can achieve this by using the variant of checkout which takes a `path` parameter.

So for example, if you already have the `master` branch checked out and you want to update the working directory so all the files look like they did in version 2.3.4

```
git checkout v2.3.4 -- .
```

This will stage all the files that have changed.  Issuing a `git status` will show you all the changed files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for [git checkout --patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

git checkout [-p|--patch] [] [--] …​
When  or --patch are given, git checkout does **not** switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named  (most often a commit). In this case, the -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an error. The  argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

Comment: That's the one! The only hitch is that it is interactive — requires user confirmation *for every file* changed. Is there a completely unattended / automatic way?

Comment: @DrakeES `yes | git checkout --patch ...` (you can add `>/dev/null` to make it quiet)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.